# regarding installation of Git

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I was working on Ubuntu 16.04.2 where I had used `sudo apt install git`. I am getting the following error:

```
$ sudo apt install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  snap-confine snapd-login-service
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  git-man liberror-perl
Suggested packages:
  git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-gui gitk gitweb git-arch git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  git git-man liberror-perl
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,932 kB of archives.
After this operation, 25,6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 liberror-perl all 0.17-1.2 [19.6 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 git-man all 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6 [736 kB]
Ign:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 git-man all 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 git amd64 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6 [3,176 kB]
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 liberror-perl all 0.17-1.2 [19.6 kB]
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 git amd64 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6
  502  Invalid headers in response [IP: 103.123.234.254 80]
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 liberror-perl all 0.17-1.2 [19.6 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 git amd64 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6 [3,176 kB]
Ign:1 http:/in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 liberror-perl all 0.17-1.2
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 git-man all 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 liberror-perl all 0.17-1.2 [19.6 kB]
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 liberror-perl all 0.17-1.2
  Undertermined Error [IP: 103.123.234.254 80]
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 git-man all 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 git amd64 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6 [3,176 kB]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 git-man all 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6
  Connection failed [IP: 103.123.234.254 80]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 git amd64 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6 [3,176 kB]
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 git amd64 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6
  Error reading from server. Remote end closed connection [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libe/liberror-perl/liberror-perl_0.17-1.2_all.deb  Undetermined Error [IP: 103.123.234.254 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/git-man_2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 103.123.234.254 80]


E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/git_2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb  Error reading from server. Remote end closed connection [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Answer (score 0):

The first three `apt` errors all happened with IP address 103.123.234.254, port 80.

The facts that this address was used both when connecting to `in.archive.ubuntu.com` and also `security.ubuntu.com` and that the DNS reverse lookup for that IP claims it to be `anycast.estointernet.in` rather than anything `*.ubuntu.com` suggest this may be a Content Delivery Network or some arrangement of your Internet Service Provider.

```
$ dig +short -x 103.123.234.254
anycast.estointernet.in.
```

The fourth error referred to IP address 91.189.91.23 for `security.ubuntu.com`.

```
$ dig +short -x 91.189.91.23
economy.canonical.com.

$ dig +short security.ubuntu.com
91.189.91.26
91.189.91.23    <-- note: here it is!
91.189.88.149
91.189.88.31
91.189.88.24
91.189.88.162
```

Looks like Canonical (the company that builds Ubuntu) has multiple servers on `security.ubuntu.com`... as expected, since the amount of traffic to it is probably huge. Each of those servers has a "proper name" in addition to the "umbrella" `security.ubuntu.com`, and your connection just happened to end up to server named `economy.canonical.com`. But it looks like that connection failed for some reason.

I don't very much like the idea that `estointernet.in` (your ISP, I assume) seems to be adding an another layer of reverse-proxy/cache/CDN technology in front of `security.ubuntu.com`: if that does not work perfectly, it may delay the availability of important security patches. But perhaps that's the only way they can deal with the amount of traffic to `security.ubuntu.com` they get.

To summarize: it looks like `estointernet.in` applies some sort of cache/proxy/CDN technology to connections going to Ubuntu's repository servers, and at the time of your connection, it looks like that technology did not work too well, and a fall-back to direct connection also failed, perhaps because of a crowded network somewhere between you and `security.ubuntu.com`

Your options are probably limited to reporting the problem to your internet connection provider and/or waiting until they fix it, or else trying a different network connection provider.